# SharePoint 2016 template

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, site-template

I'd like to know if there are a site where one can get SharePoint 2016 templates?

My client plans to upgrade to SharePoint online, but would like a new look and feel on their current 2016 SharePoint.

They do not have a big budget for it, since it is only for a few months.

Any recommendations where I can get templates for 2016 would be very much appreciated.